# I cannot get my for loop to iterate through my if statements in java

Tags: java, loops

```
        int i = 0;
        while (i > -1){
            String input = sc.nextLine();
            if(i < wordList.size()){
                if(input.equals(wordList.get(i))){
                    System.out.println(definitionList.get(i));
                    i++;
                } else if(input.equals("")){
                    i = -2;
                } else {
                    System.out.println("No matching definition");
                    
                }
            }
```

In this code I have split a dictionary file into the words and definitions, putting them in different arraylists, but i cannot figure out how to get the for loop to iterate through. It constantly stops at the first word and refuses to continue through. I have tried everything i can think of so I hope you guys have some ideas on a solution or what the issue is. Thanks a bunch.

Comment: You have a `for` loop with 3 branches, each of which have a `break` statement. Rethink your path/branch logic. Also, please format your code (Ctrl + Alt + L Intellij & Ctrl + Shift + F eclipse)

Comment: I said there was a logic error. You're breaking on the first iteration of the look regardless; it defeats the purpose of looping

Answer (score 0):

Try something more like:

```
String input = "";
do {
    System.out.print("Word: ");
    input = sc.nextLine();
    if (!input.equals("")) {
        boolean definitionFound = false;
        for(int i=0; i<wordList.size() && !definitionFound; i++){
            if(input.equals(wordList.get(i))){
                System.out.println("Definition: " + definitionList.get(i));
                definitionFound = true;
            }
        }
        if (!definitionFound) {
            System.out.println("No matching definition.");
        }
    }       
} while (!input.equals(""));
System.out.println("Goodbye!");
```

Comment: thanks so much that was super helpful